# Using a whole sentence as a subject to another sentence with gerund

Tags: sentence-construction, commas, subjects

I encountered this following sentence in an article.

> The upper critical field Hc2(T) is strongly temperature dependent, indicating a multiband superconductivity in this system.

I cannot understand its structure. Is it correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There, **indicating** might be paraphrased, "a fact that indicates" or "which indicates".

It is common for the relative **which** to refer back to the idea or fact expressed in the matrix clause. Semantically, much the same thing is going on here with the clause introduced by the present participle.

> The food critic didn't eat much, **which left** the chef in doubt whether
>   she liked his cooking.
>
> The food critic didn't eat much, **leaving** the chef in doubt whether
>   she liked his cooking.
>
> The car ran out of gas, **which caused** them to arrive late for the movie.
>
> The car ran out of gas, **causing** them to arrive late for the movie.
>
> The ambassador disagreed publicly with the leader of the country, **which made** the leader question the ambassador's loyalty.
>
> The ambassador disagreed publicly with the leader of the country, **making** the leader question the ambassador's loyalty.

Comment: Well, does that mean that using **indicating** is erroneous?

Comment: @DarkSidds: Does *what* mean that using "indicating" is erroneous? What are you referring to with "that"?

Comment: As you said, **indicating** might be paraphrased. I can interpret that there is no strict error, just a recommendation to paraphrase.

Comment: @DarkSidds: The paraphrase is to help you to understand the meaning of  such a structure. The structure is acceptable; it's not ungrammatical.